# kdb: convert 1x1 table to an atom

Tags: sql, kdb

How do I convert a table to an atom? I have a 1x1 table with a header. I want to get rid of the header and just have the number so that I do things like anotherTable*thisNumber and so on.

I've tried:

```
(raze raze tableName)
```

but this gives me: enlist 10.5, how do I get 10.5 (as a number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q)t:([] head:enlist 1)
q)t
head
----
1
q)first exec head from t
1
q) // or the shortest way 
q)t[`head]0
1
q)type first exec head from t
-7h
q)100*first exec head from t
100

q)first t`head
1
q)raze/[t]0
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you can use `over` and indexing to do this:

```
q)raze/[([]a:1#1)]0
1
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ryan example:

```
       t:([] head:enlist 1)
```

We can also simply do,

```
        first t`head
```